# Cloning in Java

Tags: java, clone, cloneable

```
class Person implements Cloneable {

    String firstName;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
     }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public Person clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
            return (Person) super.clone();
        }
   }

    Person p1 = new Person();
    p1.setFirstName("P1 Sara");

    Person p3 = new Person();
    try {
        p3 = (Person) p1.clone();
    } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
    }

    p3.setFirstName("cloned Sara");
    System.out.println("P3 : " + p3.getFirstName());
    System.out.println("P1: " + p1.getFirstName());
```

I have read that clone() method is actually a shallow copying. 
So, I assumed that when the value of a field in P3 is changed, the one in P1 would change too. 
But, that didn't happen. 
What am I missing here?

Comment: Shallow copying means that they have separate fields, but those fields refer to the same instances. It's like you copying your friend's phone number to a new phone: you just have two copies of the phone number, but they call the same phone.

Comment: String is an immutable type. That means that when you want to copy or clone it, you have a **new** instance of the String, with the copied value. If you change the cloned string, it does not impact the original string.

Comment: @AndyTurner So, in this case, P3 is a clone of P1. Shouldn't they both refer to the same firstName field?

Comment: @Sara continuing the phone analogy: you have copied the phone number onto a different phone. They are storing the same thing in two places; the two phones are *not* putting things into the same phone book. If you update it in one place, it won't update in the other place.

Comment: @KarelG Not exactly: cloning the object will not clone the strings: they both share the same instance, but if - after cloning - you update the original, it will just point to another string while the clone will continue to point to the initial string value.

Comment: @Joe That is not really a suitable duplicate, as that question concerns primitive types

Answer (score 1):

clone() method **is** actually a shallow copying.
Here's what happens in your example:

1. person1 has a reference to name. Let's call this reference A. reference A point to some place in the **heap memory**.
2. After you copy person1 to person3, the name reference in person3 (let's call it reference B) points to the same place in the heap memory. **But it is not the same reference. It's 2 different references pointing to the same place in the heap memory**.
3. When you call `p3.setFirstName("cloned Sara")`, reference B is updated to point to another place in the heap memory. There is no reason for that to change the value of where reference A is pointing.

Comment: Oh Ok. I am trying examples for cloning. How should I modify  the Person class to truly reflect shallow copying? i.e., changes in P3 reflects in P1 and vice versa?

Comment: You could replace the `String` class, which is immutable, with a mutable class, like `StringBuilder` or `StringBuffer`, and have the setter change the value inside the mutable object, rather than use operator = that points the reference somewhere else.